# How to set reverse proxy for special path in nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

How to set reverse proxy for special path in nginx?

In my Nignx's default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        # root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        root /var/www/html/website;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_pass http://107.120.30.76:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

I only know how to config the `/` root directory, how can I config the special path?

such as I request the `http://107.120.30.76/api/*` I want to transfer to `http://107.120.30.76:8000/api/*`. How to config this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the bellow configuration into the server config:

```
location /api/ {
        # root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        root /var/www/html/website;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_pass http://107.120.30.76:8001/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```